# Displaying Rotatable 3D Closed Shapes

Tags: matlab, 3d, matlab-figure, matlab-cvst

I have a list of x y z points that represent the vertices of a 3 dimensional object (a section of a brain). I would like to be able to visualize it in a 3-D plot with all its surfaces connected. I found the trisurf function in Matlab and it has almost everything that I want except it will not allow me to turn rotation on.

Is there any way to get allow me to rotate the trisurf plot? If not, what other functions would allow me to visualize a 3-D dimensional object while still being able to drag and change my view of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `trisurf` and turn rotation on using `rotate3d`. There is nothing about `trisurf` which inherently prevents rotation.

```
trisurf(data)

rotate3d on
```

Alternately, you can allow orbiting with the camera

```
cameratoolbar(gcf, 'setmode', 'orbit')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked! However, it is not allowing me to zoom in or out. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @user3315340 What do you mean it's now allowing you to? Did you try to click on the zoom button? Alternately, type `zoom on`

Comment: Every time I click on the zoom button, nothing happens. Unfortunately, zoom on did not work.

Comment: @user3315340 Are you getting any errors? What version? This absolutely works.

Comment: Never mind! I fixed it. There was something wrong with my mouse settings. My bad.